# SharedPreferences not loading in onCreate()

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to change the style of my Activity when the user clicks on a menu item.

When the user clicks on the NightMode menu item:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.night_mode:
            SharedPreferences sharedPrefStyle = getSharedPreferences(SAVE_TO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefStyle.edit();
            editor.putInt(SAVE_STYLE, R.style.nightMode);
            editor.apply();
            recreate();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Night Mode is on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Then, in my onCreate(),

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefStyle = getSharedPreferences(SAVE_TO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int style = sharedPrefStyle.getInt(SAVE_STYLE, 0);
    Log.e("style", "oncreate saved style is " + style);
    if (style != 0) {
        setTheme(style);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    // more code
}
```

But in my LogCat, this Log.e always outputs "oncreate saved style is 0," meaning nothing could be extracted from SharedPreferences.

The thing is, I tried extracting the style in onStop() and onResume(). Both successfully output the value of R.style.nightMode. So how come SharedPreferences does not work in onCreate()? Here is my LogCat for reference: So after recreate() is called,

```
E/style: onStop style: 2131755703 (this is R.style.nightMode)
E/style: onCreate style: 0
E/style: onResume style: 2131755703
```

Is there a better way to be setting the theme of an Activity at runtime? I have read through many other questions regarding this issue but cannot implement it myself. I am very new to Android so I apologize if this is trivial. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Call setContentView first.

Comment: Saving integers and retrieving from shared preferences does not work as expected. Convert to string representation before save.  Use .getString.

Comment: `apply()` is asynchronous. Have you tried using `commit()` instead?

@blackapps Storing integers into the Shared Preferences works perfectly. However I'd suggest to not store a resource id as it can create issues later when releasing an update of the app (if id has changed for any reason or resource id doesn't exist anymore).

Comment: @blackapps I have tried converting to string and calling setContentView first. It unfortunately does not work. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @Eselfar I have tried commit(), and it does not work. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Is the code in your switch, called? It doesn't appear in the logs you shared

Comment: @Eselfar Yes it is being called -- I just left out any logs that weren't my specific Log.e() commands. Also, recreate() inside the switch is being called.